# Can we have a square that also fits the definition of a circle? (Square-circle)

Tags: geometry

The only way I found that square can have a midpoint* equidistant from its sides is if we set the side lengths to be zero.

1. Similarly could you have a circle that also meets the definition of a square, say for instance if radius was set to 0?
2. In both cases, would a zero width and length square still be
   considered a square, and would a circle with radius zero still be
   considered a circle?

*If you were to draw a right-bisector through the middle of one side of a square, and another right bisector through the middle of the adjacent side the one mentioned previously, the midpoint would be where those two right bisectors intersect. In other words, a point in a square which is equidistant to all four vertices, and equidistant to the midpoints of all four sides.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Could you please explain what you mean by: 1. A "midpoint" of a square (and possibly how you measure the distance from  a midpoint to a side)? 2. A circle "fitting the definition of" a square? As written, it's not clear (to me) what you're asking. Thank you.

Comment: 1. If you were to draw a right-bisector through the middle of one side of a square, and another right bisector through the middle of the adjacent side the one mentioned previously, the midpoint would be where those two right bisectors intersect. 

In other words, a point in a square which is equidistant to all four vertices, and equidistant to the midpoints of all four sides.


2. Could you have a circle that also meets the definition of a square.

Comment: @Andrew: I think he's asking whether a single point can be considered _both_ a circle of radius $0$ _and_ a square of side length $0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes essentially this.

Comment: @user1738964: Thank you for the clarification. Your definition of "midpoint" was the natural one, but then I didn't understand "The only way [a] square can have a midpoint equidistant from its sides is if we set the side lengths to be zero." In that case, the four sides of a square are _always_ at equal distances from the center, the common distance being half the side length.  Aha...did you mean "so that the midpoint is at _constant_ distance from (each point of) each side"...?

Answer (score 3):

This is mathematics: we can define words to mean whatever we want them to mean.

That being said, it is certainly *most common* to define "circle" and "square" such that the words cover only circles/squares with positive radius/side length. According to that common usage, a single point is neither a circle nor a square.

This is not a deep necessary truth, however, but simply a convenient convention because many properties of squares and circles *do not apply* to single points -- such as "through any point on a circle there is exactly one tangent to the circle", or "two different diameters of a circle intersect it in different points". It makes it easier to formulate most theorems that we can simply say "circle" in a lot of places where we would otherwise need to say "circle of positive radius".

In comparison there are relatively few contexts where we would *want* to treat proper circles and points the same -- and in those cases it is relatively little work to start by saying that we consider a single point to be a "degenerate circle" and then say "(possibly degenerate) circle" when we state the few theorems that need this concept.